# Write to file in thread, C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, ofstream, createthread

I wrote a program, which should write "1" in thread for three seconds. But when I try to debug or add controls outputs, I realize that the thread often isn't created (no outputs in the console or achievements of debug point). When I check the return value of `CreateThread()`, it's ok. I read about log in file for I/O, but I think I don't need it. I want a program with two threads; one writing "1" for three seconds, and the second writing "2" for three seconds. Then, compare the result. Doesn't matter if "1" and "2" are mixed in the input file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <ctime>

#define NTHREAD 2

std::ofstream myfile;

DWORD WINAPI fce1 (LPVOID a){
    time_t timerStart, timerNow;
    time(&timerStart);
    timerNow = timerStart;
    while((timerNow - timerStart) < 3)
    {
        myfile << "1";
        myfile.flush();
        time(&timerNow);
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    HANDLE threads[NTHREAD];
    DWORD dwThreads[NTHREAD];

    myfile.open("file.txt");
    threads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fce1, NULL, 0, &dwThreads[0]);
    if (threads[0] == NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your main program closes the file and exits before the thread has finished running, that means that the thread might attempt to write to a closed file *and* that it will be killed with the process.

You must wait for the thread to finish before exiting the process. You can do this by, for example, using [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to poll for when the thread has exited.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of polling with `GetExitCodeThread` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Of course it would. I just haven't worked with WIN32 for such a long time, that I no longer remembers all its functions.

Comment: Yes... There is an important difference between Java and C++ In C++ the main-thread is special! When it terminates the whole Process gets killed with all other threads (all other spawned threads are just DaemonThreads)